# Debugging make on Makefile to trace where a variable/identifier name is actually declared

Tags: debugging, makefile

How to debug a make Makefile containing many Makefile scripts invocations, to trace where a variable/identifier name is actually declared/defined when that variable is being used at RHS

Comment: I'd start with `grep -r VARIABLE .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got workaround by this 'angel of savior' command:

```
$(error v = $v...... )
```

just put variable name to find out and move this line up/down to intercept curious, suspected part, although clearly laborious it's working awesome.

in tandem with pcre2grep search as better regex engine than basic...

at least for me... did prove the pudding is in the eating